# Tips for Animenz Unravel (piano)

Tags: piano, practice, classical-music

I am having some issues in playing certain parts of Unravel by Animenz. The main issue is with the right hand, I can’t keep up with the tempo and make mistakes again and again. I have practiced this slowly for some time now, but when I play on the right tempo I can’t keep up.

I don’t get what I’m doing wrong and my assumption is that it’s the technoque. So I have recorded myself to see if anyone can check it out and help me improve, perhaps?

(Note that I simplified the left hand on purpose… I still have to work on that one).

(From 90 to 93)
[image: (From 90 to 93)]

(From 108 to first half of 111)
[image]

And this is me playing these parts:

(Parts that Im looking help with are
From 00:00 to 00:12, and from 00:33 to 00:41)

I would appreciate any tip.

Comment: Please indicate the measure numbers and video timing where the problem happens.

Comment: Are you going from playing it slowly straight to playing it at tempo, or are you slowly bringing it up to tempo?

Comment: Is this played back at real speed Oo?

Comment: I've watched/listened to 0:00 to 0:12 a few times, and I don't hear or see any problems. Maybe make another video that demonstrates you missing notes or having timing problems?

Comment: A little less sustain pedal could make it easier to hear the problems. It did sound fine too me, except that the Eb in the beginning might be slightly out of tune.

Answer (score 1):

Slow work does not help because you are learning the movement to play it slow, which is not the same movement when you play it fast. It is a very common and wrong belief that slow work solves everything or most.

You want to work by segment (at speed):

1. you choose a segment (eg. 1-2 beats) where you do not feel comfortable at speed,
2. you play once it at a speed where you feel comfortable (call it slow, but it may seems not slow), you increase the consciouness and the demanding (quality) of many things: placements, sound quality, harmony, analysis eventually,
3. you imagine the movement at speed (take your time),
4. then you play it at speed,
5. if you succeed, feel (it's like a volontary thought with a feeling) that it's right, if not, feel that it's wrong and in any case, go to 3 again until you feel **comfortable** (ie., with physical relaxation, and no stress, and full consciousness ie., you never get lost).

Keep a balance of about 5-10 times points 3 to 5 for once point 2.

Then you pick another segment and then you seam them with overlapping segments or merging them or growing them and with slower and **conscious** practice (you anticipate a bit). Doing without feeling of thinking is never helping.

This is the Liszt method: "think it ten times, play it once".

Comment: Liszt's advice is excellent, but if your slow movements and fast movements are different — aside from their speed — then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Aaron It's the movement as recorded in the brain, not something specific to me. And there is nothing wrong with that, we all do that unless we are very experienced masters (Horowitz, Arguerich..).

Comment: My language was sloppy. I did not mean you specifically, I meant the general "you".

Comment: @Aaron It's the same, anybody will have a certain type of movement at low speed and another at high speed, and they are like 2 differents recordings in the brain (conscious and unconscious proprioception).

Comment: That's my point. In slow practice, it's not enough to play the notes slowly, one must use the same movements as will be used at high speed so that those movements are imprinted in the brain before attempting to play fast.